# Dates of regional tribunals

Tags: lore, ars-magica-5, ars-magica

Is it somewhere in the official sourcebooks of 5th Edition mentioned the years of the regional Tribunals?

Comment: The GotF book p.139 has a timeline at the end which supports working out the years for that tribunal, but I do not know of an official timeline with all the regional tribunals. Similar question on the Ars boards - http://forum.atlas-games.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=9007&p=136107&hilit=tribunal+timeline#p136107 , and http://forum.atlas-games.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=8531&p=127794&hilit=tribunal+timeline#p127794

Answer (score 4):

The Grand Tribunal is held every 33 years.
Some books mention Grand Tribunals in

> 1228, 1261, and 1294...

Regional Tribunals are held each seven years, also there are references of tribunals helds in:

> 1200, 1207, 1214, 1221...

Also note that regional tribunals are added/rescheduled for the year prior to a Grand Tribunal to assemble delegations.

> 1227, 1260, 1293...

And of course you can build your own timeline.

Personally I place a few regional tribunals at different years and seasons from each other.

Each troupe must determine a tribunals duration and time of year.  For example I suppose Autumn is a nice time to travel in medieval Europe (less rain, more food). But in southern Europe, Spring is also good.

Also note some tribunals have a particular timeline, like Loch Leglean[cite?] and you can schedule your regional tribunals as you deem better fits your saga.